# ros2 map not received when using slam_toolbox

Tags: slam, mapping, ros-humble, nav2

I'm working with ros2 humble and I have my robot which I can spawn successfully on gazebo and RVIZ with the set up ready of the LIDAR and the IMU sensor. The thing is when I launch:

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
```

(after launching my gazebo and rviz launch) I should see the /map topic in RVIZ but it doesn't happen.

I know the /map topic is published by slam_toolbox and RVIZ is subscribed to it. I straight follow the instructions of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaiA3hWaRzE&t=611s
, but I don't know why I can't see it on RVIZ.

Is anyone in the same situation? Maybe I skip some step? What is needed to use properly the package slam_toolbox?

The prove the map topic is published here:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out what was the issue. Slam Toolbox package works with the topic /scan by default in his file "mapper_params_online_async.yaml" (you can use your owns params if you change it) and in my URDF my LIDAR sensor sent the data on /laserscan topic. So I remapping it for /scan.

Then, in the mapper_params_online_async.yaml the default value for base_frame is base_footprint and in my robot is the base_frame so I had to change it too. After this it works properly!

Thanks Ravi and Joan!

So check the Slam params. I used this two video as a guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaiA3hWaRzE&t=611s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMTxb8Y2cxI&t=268s

Comment: Also... I would check if mapping mode is localization or mapping. I think with just localization it only publishes odom and no map

Answer (score 0):

Need more info of the system.

Can you update the post with the config file and also provide the tf tree.

Run when you launch everything: ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames

Comment: Hi Ravi, thank you for your answer. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to know which can be the problem.

Be sure that the slam_toolbox is receiving the messages from odometry and laser (correct topic, check with rqt > Node graph plugin, for example).